# How to add a downloaded .box file to Vagrant?

Tags: windows, vagrant

How do I add a downloaded `.box` file to Vagrant's list of available boxes? The `.box` file is located on an external drive.

I tried running `vagrant box add my-box d:/path/to/box`, but Vagrant interprets the path as a URL.

Comment: Could you post the whole output along with vagrant version? Theoretically vagrant box add should work like a charm with local file paths

Comment: I'm in Ubuntu, and `vagrant box add my-box /path/to/file.box` worked fine for me.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

### Solution:

```
vagrant box add my-box file:///d:/path/to/file.box
```

Has to be in a URL format.

Comment: what if i use `vagrant box add my-box ./path/to/mybox.box ?`

Comment: you can also pass `-f` to force it to download the box again, and replace it if it already exists. e.g. `vagrant box add -f my-box http://some-url`

Comment: vagrant under macos and linux (2.2.2) works with a nun URI path to, so the scheme file:// can be omitted here at least. Maybe that a version specific change or its windows specific, i rather expect the latter one

Answer (score 105):

You can point to the folder where vagrant and copy the box file to same location. Then after you may run as follows

```
vagrant box add my-box name-of-the-box.box
vagrant init my-box
vagrant up
```

Just to check status

```
vagrant status
```

Comment: i did `vagrant init` and `vagrant up` and my vagrant box is running. But i can't ssh. When i do `vagrant ssh` it says "The machine you're attempting to SSH into is configured to use password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script entering the password for you. If you're prompted for a password, please enter the same password you have configured in the Vagrantfile." whereas i didn't configure anything in the `Vagrantfile`. I am just using the `Vagrantfile` that got automatically created upon `vagrant init`. When i `cat Vagrantfile`, I don't see anything called a password or pem or anything

Comment: If `vagrant ssh` is asking for a password, and the base box you're using is public, chances are the password is `vagrant`.

Comment: I have the same error and password    vagrant  didn't solve it

Comment: The password for the [modern.ie](https://modern.ie) Microsoft boxes is `Passw0rd!`

Comment: To everybody who cannot ssh afterwards, the problem originates from the box export. You need to add the Vagrant insecure public key to the authorized keys again. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075461/how-do-i-add-my-own-public-key-to-vagrant-vm

Answer (score 28):

Try to change directory to where the `.box` is saved

Run `vagrant box add my-box downloaded.box`, this may work as it avoids absolute path (on Windows?).

Comment: i did `vagrant init` and `vagrant up` and my vagrant box is running. But i can't ssh. When i do `vagrant ssh` it says "The machine you're attempting to SSH into is configured to use password-based authentication. Vagrant can't script entering the password for you. If you're prompted for a password, please enter the same password you have configured in the Vagrantfile." whereas i didn't configure anything in the `Vagrantfile`. I am just using the `Vagrantfile` that got automatically created upon `vagrant init`. When i `cat Vagrantfile`, I don't see anything called a password or pem or anything

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively to add downloaded box, a json file with metadata can be created. This way some additional details can be applied. For example to import box and specifying its version create file:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/homestead",
  "versions": [
    {
      "version": "7.0.0",
      "providers": [
        {
          "name": "virtualbox",
          "url": "file:///path/to/box/virtualbox.box"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Then run `vagrant box add` command with parameter:

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead /path/to/metadata.json
```

Comment: Finally a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

**Solution for Windows:**

- Open the cmd or powershell as admin
- CD into the folder containing the `.box` file
- `vagrant box add --name name_of_my_box 'name_of_my_box.box'`
- `vagrant box list` should show the new box in the list

**Solution for MAC:**

- Open terminal
- CD into the folder containing the `.box` file
- `vagrant box add --name name_of_my_box "./name_of_my_box.box"`
- `vagrant box list` should show the new box in the list

Answer (score 5):

First rename the Vagrantfile
then

```
vagrant box add new-box name-of-the-box.box
vagrant init new-box
vagrant up
```

Just to check status

```
vagrant status
```

that's all

Answer (score 3):

```
F:\PuppetLab\src\boxes>vagrant box add precise32 file:///F:/PuppetLab/src/boxes/precise32.box
==> box: Adding box 'precise32' (v0) for provider:
    box: Downloading: file:///F:/PuppetLab/src/boxes/precise32.box
    box: Progress: 100% (Rate: 1200k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> box: Successfully added box 'precise32' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add description for another one case. I've got to install similar Vagrant Ubuntu 18.04 based configurations to multiple Ubuntu machines. Downloaded bionic64 box to one using `vagrant up` with `Vagrantfile` where this box was specified, then copied folder `.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-bionic64` to others.