# Vagrant up hangs on waiting for ssh

Tags: vagrant

I'm running vagrant with the `libvirt` provider, trying to run an `arch` box (`archlinux/archlinux`).
When running `vagrant up`, the command hangs when waiting for ssh to become available.
Note that if I run `vagrant ssh` from another window, it succeeds and I have a valid ssh session.
When running `vagrant up --debug`, I can see the following problem:

```
DEBUG ssh: Checking whether SSH is ready...
DEBUG ssh: Checking key permissions: /home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
 INFO ssh: Attempting SSH connection...
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 192.168.121.35
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 22
 INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
 INFO ssh:   - Password? false
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["/home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
DEBUG ssh:   - connect_opts: {:auth_methods=>["none", "hostbased", "publickey"], :config=>false, :forward_agent=>false, :send_env=>false, :keys_only=>true, :verify_host_key=>:never, :password=>nil, :port=>22, :timeout=>15, :user_known_hosts_file=>[], :verbose=>:debug, :encryption=>["aes256-ctr", "aes192-ctr", "aes128-ctr", "aes256-cbc", "aes192-cbc", "aes128-cbc", "rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se"
, "blowfish-ctr", "blowfish-cbc", "cast128-ctr", "cast128-cbc", "3des-ctr", "3des-cbc", "idea-cbc", "arcfour256", "arcfour128", "arcfour", "none"], :logger=>#<Logger:0x0000556be9229048 @level=0, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x0000556be9228f58 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=nil, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x0000556be9228ee0 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil,
 @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<StringIO:0x0000556be92290c0>, @binmode=false, @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x0000556be9228eb8>, @mon_data_owner_object_id=335760>>, :keys=>["/home/user/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"], :remote_user=>"vagrant"}
DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log START ==
DEBUG ssh: D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.961548 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[51fa4]: establishing connection to 192.168.121.35:22
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.962412 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.session[51fa4]: connection established
I, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.962478 #1115770]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[51fb8]: negotiating protocol version
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.962494 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[51fb8]: local is `SSH-2.0-Ruby/Net::SSH_5.2.0 x86_64-linux-gnu'
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.976104 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.server_version[51fb8]: remote is `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.3'
I, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.976371 #1115770]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[51fcc]: sending KEXINIT
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.976563 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: queueing packet nr 0 type 20 len 1324
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.976685 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: sent 1328 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.978750 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: read 1080 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.978823 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: received packet nr 0 type 20 len 1076
I, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.978863 #1115770]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[51fcc]: got KEXINIT from server
I, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.978942 #1115770]  INFO -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[51fcc]: negotiating algorithms
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.979021 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[51fcc]: negotiated:
* kex: ecdh-sha2-nistp521
* host_key: ssh-ed25519
* encryption_server: aes256-ctr
* encryption_client: aes256-ctr
* hmac_client: hmac-sha2-512
* hmac_server: hmac-sha2-512
* compression_client: none
* compression_server: none
* language_client:
* language_server:
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.979035 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.transport.algorithms[51fcc]: exchanging keys
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.979863 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: queueing packet nr 1 type 30 len 148
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.979989 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: sent 152 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.983267 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: read 312 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.983347 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: received packet nr 1 type 31 len 292
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.984471 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: queueing packet nr 2 type 21 len 20
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.984561 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: sent 24 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.984636 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: received packet nr 2 type 21 len 12
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.984844 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[51ff4]: beginning authentication of `vagrant'
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.984943 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: queueing packet nr 3 type 5 len 28
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:37.984968 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: sent 96 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.026842 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: read 96 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.027017 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: received packet nr 3 type 6 len 28
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.027108 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[51ff4]: trying none
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.027709 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: queueing packet nr 4 type 50 len 44
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.027963 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: sent 112 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.035112 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: read 112 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.035201 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: received packet nr 4 type 51 len 44
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.035252 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[51ff4]: allowed methods: publickey,password
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.035289 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.none[52008]: none failed
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.035329 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[51ff4]: trying publickey
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.036018 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[5201c]: connecting to ssh-agent
E, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.036216 #1115770] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.agent[5201c]: could not connect to ssh-agent: Agent not configured
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.036362 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.methods.publickey[52044]: trying publickey (dd:3b:b8:2e:85:04:06:e9:ab:ff:a8:0a:c0:04:6e:d6)
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.036491 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: queueing packet nr 5 type 50 len 348
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.036606 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: sent 416 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.043689 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: read 112 bytes
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.043785 #1115770] DEBUG -- socket[51fe0]: received packet nr 5 type 51 len 44
D, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.043829 #1115770] DEBUG -- net.ssh.authentication.session[51ff4]: allowed methods: publickey,password
E, [2023-05-10T16:53:38.043850 #1115770] ERROR -- net.ssh.authentication.session[51ff4]: all authorization methods failed (tried none, publickey)

DEBUG ssh: == Net-SSH connection debug-level log END ==
 INFO ssh: SSH not up: #<Vagrant::Errors::SSHAuthenticationFailed: SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well.>
```

The suspicious line is `could not connect to ssh-agent: Agent not configured`, but ssh-agent is indeed configured and running.

My Vagrantfile is

```
  Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "archlinux/archlinux"

    config.vm.provider :libvirt do |domain|
      domain.memory = 2048
      domain.cpus = 4
    end

  end
```

I tried `eval $(ssh-agent) -s` to start it and to run `ssh-add`, but it didn't help.
Also tried the solution in [How do I add my own public key to Vagrant VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075461/how-do-i-add-my-own-public-key-to-vagrant-vm), and it doesn't work either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because from the vagrant tag: GENERAL VAGRANT SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Its a lab?

```
vagrant destroy
vagrant up
```

dont waste your time.